# PyQt: Prevent Resize and Maximize in QDialog?

Tags: python, resize, pyqt, qdialog

How can I prevent a QDialog in PyQt from being resizeable or maximazable? I don't want the window's size changed.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Use [setFixedSize](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#setFixedSize-2):

```
mydialog.setFixedSize(width, height)
```

Comment: `self.setFixedSize(self.size())` to set it to always be the current size

Answer (score 5):

The above answers are just fine,
besides, you could set **maximum** and **mini** widths and heights manually,
like this:

```
myDialog = QDialog()
myDialog.setMaximumWidth(myDialog.width())
myDialog.setMaximumHeight(myDialog.height())
```

or in short, you could use maximumSize as:

```
myDialog.setMaximumSize()
```

Just as in the above code....

Answer (score 0):

To set **fixed sized** *window* or *dialog box* (*QWidget in general*) you could use **[setFixedSize](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/api/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#setFixedSize)([QSize](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/api/qtcore/qsize.html))** or **setFixedSize(int, int)** functions.

In PyQt5, use :-

```
custom_dialog.setFixedSize(QSize(width, height)) # setFixedSize(QSize)
```

or

```
custom_dialog.setFixedSize(width, height) # setFixedSize(int, int)
```

You must import

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import  QSize
```

You could also use

```
custom_dialog.setFixedSize(custom_dialog.size())
```

Other Related Functions

[setFixedWidth](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/api/qtwidgets/qwidget.html?#setFixedWidth)(int)

[setFixedHeight](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/api/qtwidgets/qwidget.html?#setFixedWidth)(int)